# Looking to alter php Wordpress plugin form input from toggle to radio with 3 options

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am helping out a local library and know next to nothing about php, but one of the wordpress plugins they are using requires me to add another form field input to be filled out.

The plugin dev provided sample code to use as a yes/no input for their forms, but I need to make it a radio input instead with the option to choose one of 3 color options - blue, red or yellow?

Hoping someone can help me alter the code below to do that.

Thank you in advance.

```php
// BEGIN EVENTON CODE

add_filter('evoau_form_fields', 'evoautest_fields_to_form', 10, 1);
function evoautest_fields_to_form($array){
    $array['evotest']=array('Test Fields', 'evotest', 'evotest','custom','');
    return $array;
}

// actionUser integration
add_action('evoau_frontform_evotest',  'evoautest_fields', 10, 6);  

// Frontend showing fields and saving values  
function evoautest_fields($field, $event_id, $default_val, $EPMV, $opt2, $lang){
    $helper = new evo_helper();
    echo "<div class='row evotest'><p>";
        $evoau_test_value = ($EPMV && !empty($EPMV['evoau_test_value']) && $EPMV['evoau_test_value'][0]=='yes')? true: false;
        echo $helper->html_yesnobtn(array(
            'id'=>'evoau_test_value',
            'input'=>true,
            'label'=>evo_lang_get('evoAULtest_1', 'Test Input Field', $lang, $opt2),
            'var'=> ($evoau_test_value?'yes':'no'),
            'lang'=>$lang,
            'afterstatement'=>'evoau_test_value_section'
        ));

    echo "</p></div>";
}
// save the values to event post meta
add_action('evoau_save_formfields',  'evoautest_save_values', 10, 3);
function evoautest_save_values($field, $fn, $created_event_id){
    if( $field =='evotest'){
        
        // for each above fields
        foreach(array(
            'evoau_test_value',
        ) as $field){
            if(!empty($_POST[$field]))
                add_post_meta($created_event_id, $field, $_POST[$field]);
        }
    }
}

// END EVENTON CODE
```

Comment: Looks like all this code is just copy&pasted from https://docs.myeventon.com/documentations/add-additional-fields-actionuser-event-submission-form/ - and there it says, _"I am using the evo_helper() class and using the html_yesnobtn() function to output a neatly styles yes/no field on event submission form. You can type your own custom HTML in here instead."_ - I can't tell by a glance at the documentation, what alternatives to `html_yesnobtn` this class might provide - if there aren't any, for what specifically you want here, then you can write your own form field code directly.

Comment: Thank you fro your response. And yes the code it directly copied from there. I am just not a programmer and have been trying to figure out how to switch it with no luck so far.

Comment: What I would like to do is have a radio option where the user would choose 1 of 3 choices, instead of  the yes/no option.